# How to solve equation involving Chebyshev polynomial ratio?: $\frac{\cos\big(\frac{\cos^{-1}(ya)}{2N}\big)}{\cos\big(\frac{\cos^{-1}(y)}{2N}\big)}=x$

Tags: problem-solving, chebyshev-polynomials

I have the following equation: [involving the ratio of two Chebyshev polynomials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgUyu.png):

> $$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\cos^{-1}(ya)}{2N}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\cos^{-1}(y)}{2N}\right)}=x$$

(for some reason, I am unable to type equations here even though I did exactly as the tutorials told me to)

where $a$ is an constant

I am unable to get the equation in terms of $x$. I couldn't find any identity involving the ratio of two chebyshev polynomials and couldn't think of any useful approaches.

Is there any way to get the equation in terms of $x$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).